# Get elements coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I need some help here.
First off, here is a small demo code from my game: https://jsfiddle.net/MiloSx7/a0dn9a4f/2/

Animation idea: Make the coin scale to 2x after it's collected, then slowly move it and gradually reduce scale to the exact spot where the image displaying the coin inventory stat is , `invLocation` is the ID of the element where the animation should end. It starts from the current `coinId` X and Y
Is it possible to somehow get the X and Y of the `invLocation`, so that I know where should I tell the animation to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JQuery position() and offset() methods.

```
const spawnTime = 10000;

var coin = 0;
var intervalId = '';

var coinDiv = $('#coinDiv');
var coinImg = $('#coinImg');
var invDiv  = $('#invDiv');
var invId   = $('#inventoryId');
var invImg  = $('#invLocation');


coinImg.on('click', collect);
intervalId = setInterval(setLocation, spawnTime);


function setLocation() {
  var x = parseInt( Math.random()*(80-20+1) ) + 20;
  var y = parseInt( Math.random()*(80-20+1) ) + 20;

  coinImg.animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 3000,
  function() {
    coinImg.css('top', x+'%');
    coinImg.css('left', y+'%');
    coinImg.css('display', 'initial');

    setTimeout( () => coinImg.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000), 6000);
  });
}

function collect() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);

  coinImg.stop();
  coinImg.css('opacity', 1);

  /* Increment coin counter */
  coin++;
  invId.text(coin);

  /* In order to disable multiple clicks */
  coinImg.css('pointer-events', 'none');

  /* Double the size */
  coinImg.css('width', '128px');
  coinImg.css('height', '128px');

  /* Animate and return to normal */
  coinImg.animate({
        width:  '32px',
        height: '32px',
        left:   invImg.offset().left + 'px',
        top:    invImg.offset().top  + 'px'
    }, 1500,
    function() {
      coinImg.css('pointer-events', 'auto');
      coinImg.css('display', 'none');
      coinImg.css('width', '64px');
      coinImg.css('height', '64px');

      intervalId = setInterval(setLocation, spawnTime);
    }
  );
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wz4q9w69/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, my initial goal with this game was to learn JS, I never looked into jQ and I don't quite understand it. However, I was able to do it with JS using `elem.getBoundingClientRect();` , it works exactly as your example. Have a nice day